# add new template role to existing docusign envelope with status 'sent'

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to implement embeded signing using docusign, where we have two template roles. I know one of them initialy. So I'm creating an new envelope with the known role. After he signs I need to update the existing envelope with the second template role, I'm unable to do so.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
envDef = new (docusign.EnvelopeDefinition)

assigneeRole = new (docusign.TemplateRole)
assigneeRole.setRoleName templateRoleNames[1]
assigneeRole.setName assignee.fullName
assigneeRole.setEmail assignee.email
assigneeRole.setClientUserId assignee.id

# create a list of template roles and add our newly created role
templateRolesList = [assigneeRole]

# assign template role(s) to the envelope
envDef.setTemplateRoles templateRolesList


envelopesApi = new (docusign.EnvelopesApi)

await envelopesApi.update accountId, envelopeId, envDef, {advanced_update: 'true'}, defer(err, envelopeUpdateSummary, response)
if err
   next err
   return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the existing recipient (from the template) is the last recipient, then after that recipient signs, the envelope will (very) quickly become `complete`.

So you need to update the recipients **before** the first recipient has signed. Try [EnvelopeRecipients::create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/create/)

You should also add a tab for the new recipient, else she will need to manually add a signing tab which is not a good user experience.

Another idea is to create the template with a dummy signer (whose email goes to a black hole email). Then update the envelope to correct the second signer' information.

Comment: If the second signer declined document, should I reinitialize entire process or is there a way to continue from step 1 (i.e without the need for the signer 1 to sign again).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the rules involving a decline to sign. Please ask a new question on StackOverflow.